# How to insert a Relative button inside a Cell in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a relative button inside a cell in excel. Actually, what I want is, A button which is inside a cell and can move relatively when rows/columns are added/deleted. Moreover, I want it to load a specific text in a cell below the cell where button is contained. Can that be done in excel? I am  not sure how to proceed! New to VB!! Any help appreciated :)

EDIT::

To position a relative button I am using the following code:

```
Sub buttonInACell()
Dim btn As Button
Dim t

   Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 6)
   Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

End Sub
```

Now I need to add a macro to the button to load a value in a cell below it.. I think i should be using `TopLeftCell` property. But how can i refer to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a macro to the button you can use its OnAction property - set that to the name of the macro you want to call. Inside that macro you can use Application.Caller to get the name of the button, and use that name to dtermine what action to take.

```
Sub buttonInACell()
Dim btn As Button
Dim t, x

   For x = 1 To 5
        Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, x)
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        btn.OnAction = "ClickedMe"
   Next x

End Sub

Sub ClickedMe()

    Dim c, s
    c = Application.Caller
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(c)
    s.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "clicked"


End Sub
```

Comment: I am also doing the same thing .. one doubt, can you tell me how can i check if a value exists in a cell using vba? is it, If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value = Null Then

Comment: I would typically use `If Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value) = 0`.  Possibly `If Len(Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value)) = 0` just to be sure ;-)

Comment: I tried, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value = "" .. This works!!

Comment: can you tell me what does t.left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height do in ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height) ?

Comment: It adds a button with the specified size, at the specified position

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tim for the answer! Actually i tired to figure out myself a bit and I reached a solution as per my requirement, which is as :

To Put button in a cell ::

```
Sub buttonInACell()
Dim btn As Button
Dim t

   Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 6)
   Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

End Sub
```

On click of the button ::

```
Public flag As Integer

Sub buttonInACell_Click()

Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

    'flag=0 : no show, flag=1 : show

    row = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row
    col = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column

    If flag = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters.text = "Show data"
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Font.Color = vbRed Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Value = ""
            End If
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Font.Color = vbWhite
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).WrapText = False
        flag = 1

    ElseIf flag = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters.text = "Hide Data"
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Value = "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).WrapText = True
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Font.Color = vbRed
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Value = "Sorry! No Sample Data As of Yet!"
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).WrapText = True
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 2, col).Font.Color = vbBlack
            End If
        flag = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

What this actually does is, it creates a toggle button and allows data in a relative cell to be toggled! :)